# CF - TabControl - how to make the tabs bigger?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control with tab pages (cf).

The tabs are too small ... can some1 tell me how can i make them bigger?

Comment: did u mean increase the size of tab page??

Comment: no not a tab page, but the actual tab that the user presses on. Hans proposal works, tho its a shame there is no direct property

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Increase the size of the TabControl's Font.  That takes care of the height.  If they are not wide enough then put more text in them.  Or set the SizeMode property to Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The tab size is set by the `ItemSize` property on the tab control.

Answer (score 1):

Changing SizeMode property to FillToRight\FillToLeft does the trick.
Then you can enlarge the font and both height and width of the tab will grow.

Answer (score 1):

Change ItemSize property in properties window. You can change width and height of the tabs using this property.